# Using a separate file handle to read a temporary file created using File::Temp

Tags: perl, temp, filehandle

I created a temporary file using File::Temp and added some data to it. At some other point of time, I would like to read the temporary file, using a separate file handle (seek method works). Following is the code snippet.

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile( SUFFIX => '.txt' );
my $towrite = "XXXX\nYYYY\nZZZZ\n";

open ANOTHERFH, "<", $fh or die "Cannot open $FH\n";
while (<ANOTHERFH>) {
   print "ANOTHERFH: $_";
}
close ANOTHERFH;
```

However, I get an error stating "Can't open GLOB...."
Any suggestions

Comment: Third arg to `open` should be a filename (so `$filename`), not a file handle (`$fh`).

Answer (score 1):

To clone ("dup") a system file handle, the syntax is

```
open(my $fh, '<&', $fh_to_dup)          # dups into a new fd
```

or

```
open($existing_fh, '<&=', $fh_to_dup)   # dupds into fd fileno($existing_fh)
```

so you want

```
open(my $ANOTHER_FH, "<&", $fh)         # Avoid needless use of globals!
   or die("Can't dup temp file: $!\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$filename` instead of `$fh`:

```
open ANOTHERFH, "<", $filename   or die "Cannot open $filename\n";
```

Or use `dup` as @ikegami suggest